# How to hide links in masterpage for some roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

How can I hide hyperlinks in my Masterpage from users with specific role? I'm using Identity framework for providing users and Roles. My application is in MVC4.

I want the following links to be hidden for users:

```
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/Management/Reports.aspx">Reports</asp:HyperLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/Management/Management.aspx">Management</asp:HyperLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/Roles/ManageUserRoles.aspx">Roles</asp:HyperLink>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make them visible="false" and in the codeBehind in page_load you can check from the HTTPContext `users.identity.name` or something like that and if it matches something you can show it. It is quite specific how you want to work with your users but to your question this is what I can tell you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This Solved my Problem